# Parse a graph url string C#

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following string

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/group-id/members/user-id/$ref

How do I parse the url string and get the value user-id?

```
var a = requestStep; //requestStep is of type Microsoft.Graph.BatchRequestStep
var b = requestStep.Request.RequestUri;
```

b has the value:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/group-id/members/user-id/$ref

[image]

Comment: `var userId = b.Split('/')[7]`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to skin that cat ...

```
string url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/group-id/members/user-id/$ref";
string userId = url.Split('/')[url.Split('/').Length - 1];
Console.WriteLine(userId);
```

Comment: As a suggestion, you can do `url.Split('/')[^2]` to get `user-id` and `url.Split('/')[^1]` to get `$ref`.

Comment: Wow, you learn something new everyday.

Comment: @gunr2171 just tried that and it didn't work for me, was just using .NET fiddle.  Also looked up doco and nothing came up.  If you get 5, can you share the doco that explains that concept?

Comment: [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemindex) and [fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BCpacs)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following regex pattern :

```
^https:\/\/graph\.microsoft\.com\/.+\/members\/(.+)\/\$ref$
```

[image]